# Flutter: Android 12 keyboard showing white space

Tags: flutter, android-12

I am implementing a Flutter app having TextFormField in my login screen to capture credentials. When I ran it on Android Emulator with 12.0 or real device with Android 12 it is showing white container instead of keyboard. It is happening with Android 12 only.

What can I try next?

Note: It is working fine on all iOS Versions.

```
return Form(
        key: _formKeySignInInputs,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 8.vw),
                      child: buildEmailFormField()),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 2.vw),
                      child: buildPasswordFormField()),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.vw, 0, 0, 4.vw),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }


  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
    var localeContext = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

    return TextFormField(
      autocorrect: false,
      obscureText: true,
      enableSuggestions: false,
      onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: localeContext.password_null_error);
        } else if (value.length >= 4) {
          removeError(error: localeContext.short_password_error);
        }
        return;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: localeContext.password_null_error);
          return "";
        } else if (value.length < 4) {
          addError(error: localeContext.short_password_error);
          return "";
        }
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: localeContext.password,
        hintText: localeContext.password_hint,
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: const InputFieldSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/password.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    var localeContext = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

    return TextFormField(
      autocorrect: false,
      enableSuggestions: false,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: localeContext.email_null_error);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: localeContext.invalid_email_error);
        }
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: localeContext.email_null_error);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: localeContext.invalid_email_error);
          return "";
        }
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: localeContext.email,
        hintText: localeContext.email_hint,
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: const InputFieldSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/temp/mail.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you share your code? Do you have nested Scaffold widgets?

Comment: @BurakAkkaş, I have updated my code above, could you please check? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue of the disabled `Hardware Acceleration` feature in the **Android** native subproject, for more details, refer to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75939361/11217945).