# Flutter: keyboard is showing as a white box in Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, keyboard

In a Flutter App, I have a `TextField` at somewhere, when I tap on the field while running on **Android** to type something, the keyboard is not showing up, instead a **White Box** with the same area of the keyboard is showing.

I am facing the issue in everything that has a keyboard inside the app, I mean not just the `TextField` widget, I am also facing it with `TextFormField` too and the issue doesn't exist on **IOS**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Quick Suggestion:

Make sure the **Hardware Acceleration** feature is enabled for the android project.

Inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, check if you have the property `android:hardwareAccelerated` set to true like the following:

```xml
<application>
    <activity
        ...
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        ... >
    ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

**NOTE:** If you don't see it while your `Android API >= 14` then it is enabled by default.

If it was not enabled, then enable it, stop the app & rerun it, and check if the problem is solved or not.

---

##### Details:

Since you mentioned that the problem is only in **Android**, then it might be strongly related to the [Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/hardware-accel) feature, here is a brief description about it:

> Beginning in Android 3.0 (API level 11), the Android 2D rendering pipeline supports hardware acceleration, meaning that all drawing operations that are performed on a View's canvas use the GPU. Because of the increased resources required to enable hardware acceleration, your app will consume more RAM.

Having the `Hardware Acceleration` disabled can cause issues such as **invisible elements (might be your case)**, exceptions, or wrongly rendered pixels, that's why I'm guessing it's the problem.